# Codeigniter Dynamic CSS

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Is there any dynamic css creation is available for codeigniter?

Like this in cakephp : http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/t73net/2007/06/22/dynamic-css-for-cms-and-more#page-3

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. It is the most horrible idea, that i have seen today.

Comment: Agreed with tereško. If you still want to try it out, there are PHP/CI ports of LESS, SASS and minify.

Comment: Why in the world? I guess for theme customizations? I'd suggest creating a template with macros you can swap out and cache as changes are made.

Comment: There are use cases for this, although I'd like to see what the aim is here.

Comment: Please go through the link provided by me and tell is there any way similar to that in Codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

[This project](https://github.com/ju1ius/css-parser) is in PHP, and lets you parse and create stylesheets. It's not mine, but I've used it quite successfully.